# auth/argument-error facebook OAuth with firebase

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two options to signin with firebase SDK:
1- signin() that uses email and password
2- facebook() that uses `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();`
Why My  `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult(provider)` is calling the `auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword` which is in completly another funtion (login()) ?

and I have the following error: `Pi {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "getRedirectResult failed: Expected 0 arguments but got 1."}`

Any Idea please ?

Comment: `Pi {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "getRedirectResult failed: Expected 0 arguments but got 1."}` that's means you don't need to pass argument

Comment: you don't need to pass `provider` object

Comment: Remember that in your Firebase dashboard you've to activate any of the functions for authenticate

Comment: Thank you Kenry. I don't have this error anymore, but it still don't get login. 
Why right after the getRedirectResult is finished the auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword is called and an error occur saying that the parameter 'User 'is undefined. auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword is in another function, and in my code I do not call it from getRedirectResult function.

Comment: Well, it is working now, I found out that I had another function that verifies the EmailVerified when the user uses the email & password, and that function did not permit the access. It's a little bit confusing when managing the facebook login and the classic email & password login method as well.. !!

Comment: Still, do you know why $signInWithEmailAndPassword is called when I use facebook loginoption ??

Comment: I really don't know why but, I would imagine that maybe like you need to set an email and a password, maybe the Facebook login process used it for authenticating email and password and really you are setting an email and password, it's the same but I'm not sure. I'd read the API for that explanation.